# Ember.js isDestroyed observer not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement a flash messages service in Ember.js, taking inspiration from [this article](https://medium.com/delightful-ui-for-ember-apps/adding-flash-messages-to-an-ember-app-437b13e49c1b).

This gist is:
The flash messages are Ember Objects in an Array. When one gets destroyed it should be automatically removed from the array.

Here is my example that shows the isDestroyed observer not firing
http://jsbin.com/qihafu/3/edit?js,console

I'd be grateful if anybody could explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs about the `isDestroyed` flag (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html#property_isDestroyed):

> if this property is true the **observers and bindings were already removed** by the effect of calling the destroy() method.

Perhaps you want the `willDestroy` hook.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I missed the docs reference.

I'm left wondering how does it work in the article referenced in my original post?

Comment: That example is not **observing** the isDestroyed flag as you are trying to do. Instead, it's **examining** the flag, which is fine.

Comment: Ok. I see.
(Although it does say 'queue.@each.isDestroyed')

Comment: Glad to hear things are working. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.